# Job Apply Button Validation from sheetsu API using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, spreadsheet, edit

**Details** - First Visit this link - http://www.flacement.com/jobssearch/iffco-tokio-job-in-jharsuguda/

its created by WP and Plugin is **Jobs for Wordpress by Blueglass**

**what i want** -- when someone click apply , some one can apply via flacement ID but i want to validate that ID from sheetsu JS API and Insert that code in backend code.

**what i need you to help me**

here is sheetsu api code

```
<head>
  <script src="//script.sheetsu.com/"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    function successFunc(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
    // Get all rows where column 'adhar_no' is '3894-8873-7149'
    var searchQuery = {
      status: active,
    };
    Sheetsu.read("https://sheetsu.com/apis/v1.0dh/dd98887de543/", {
      search: searchQuery
    }, successFunc);
  </script>
</body>
```

when some one write `flacement ID ( 3894-8873-7149)` its search from sheestu API 
`if value= active then proceed else` , `alert > your are block`.
`if value= not found then` , `alert > register here`

please make me a JS validation script with HTML

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input-text_flacement-id');
    var is_focused = false;

    input.onfocus = function () {
        is_focused = true;
    }

    input.onblur = function () {
        if (is_focused) {
            is_focused = false;
            check_id(input.value);
        }
    }

    function check_id(id) {
        if (id.match(/\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}/)) {
            document.body.append("\nchecking...");
            function successFunc(data) {
                var row = data.filter((row)=>row['adhar_no'] == id)
                if(row.length){
                    document.body.append("\nid found");
                }
                else{
                    document.body.append('\nid not found');
                }
            }
            // Get all rows where column 'adhar_no' is '3894-8873-7149'
            var searchQuery = {
                status: 'active',
            };
            Sheetsu.read("https://sheetsu.com/apis/v1.0dh/dd98887de543/", {
                search: searchQuery
            }, successFunc);
        }
        else {
            document.body.append('\ninvalid id');
        }
    }
```

```html
<input id="input-text_flacement-id">

<script src="https://script.sheetsu.com/"></script>
```

**NOTE:** try not using this `is_focused` technique

Comment: Thank you its working now brother. if i'll face any problem will ask you here. tahnk you again